# Почему маска конфликтует с атрибутом readonly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attr, readonly

Есть маска, задается инпуту при загрузке странице

```
$phone.mask("0299999999", {string: '{{ form_label(form.phone) }}'})
```

после отправки данных ставится атрибут этому инпуту

```
$phone.attr('readonly',true);
```

Почему в консоле просматривая код инпута можно увидеть  что readonly='readonly'
а редактировать поле всё равно можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что атрибут readonly проверяется браузером только на этапе построения DOM. Когда DOM уже построен - вместо атрибута надо использовать соответствующее свойство:

```
$phone.prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: таким образом в тег прописывается атрибут только readonly, нежели при attr когда прописывается и readonly='readonly' . И тоже не работает